# How to forecast changepoints from Gas Concentration Data?

Tags: time-series, logistic, forecasting, svm, change-point

So I'm trying to predict when gas concentrations change from sensor conductivity readings over a day. The gases randomly change concentrations around every 80-120 seconds and are kept constant between changes. There are two gases - methane and ethylene. Right now, I'm just trying to predict when the changepoints occur in methane concentrations.

I've added a variable that indicates whether that gas concentration changes. Next, I've split the data into train and test (where the train data is the first half of the day, and the test data is the last half of the day). For reference, here are some time plots of the sensors and the gas concentrations:

[image: Time plot of sensors and gas concentrations]

One of the sensors from the dataset was broken (sensor 2), so it was removed.

I have tried fitting sklearn's logistic regression and linear SVC to predict the changepoints, and even set the classweights to balanced since there are very few changepoints (data measurements were taken every 1/100th of a second). However, logistic regression ends up predicting too many changepoints for the test data and linear SVR fails to converge.

Since my approach wasn't working, I was looking for suggestions of how to approach this problem.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jawi. What information are you using to make your predictions?  Are the changepoints independent of the previous history or not?  You increase your chances of receiving on point, constructive comments and answers when you summarize your data and explain your assumptions.

Comment: Hello whuber, I have edited my response a bit to make it a bit more clear about what I have done. I believe the changepoints are independent of previous history since the site I got the data from said that the gas concentrations are randomly changed after 80-120 second intervals. For making the predictions, I am training the sklearn logistic regression and Linear SVC on the training data, and then using them to make predictions. Please let me know if you need anything else.